# Is there a way to create embed codes from wordpress/buddypress content?

Tags: embed, code

I am looking for a way to create embed codes for content like,  posts,  images,  videos,  comments and buddypress content and components to be posted on external websites and apps.

So for instance say my users upload a video and they want to embed the video on another site without using another service.

Or if someone wants to embed a post or BP activity module,  this can be done with embed codes.

Hopefully this can be accomplished.

Comment: You could always use a third party service like YouTube, Vimeo or something. For almost anything, there's a third-party service. You could also link to content to your website.

Comment: PS, I also found a shortcode for WordPress, you could do something like that with javascript. It will require a bit of programming, see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode

Comment: I am hosting my users videos,  YouTube  won't  work. I don't  just need videos but posts,  buddypress activity basically anything.

Comment: Nobody has a solution for this?

Comment: It seems like you have asked a difficult question, most of the time I see questions answered within minutes. Everybody likes to earn their points/reputation. It looks like you have asked a hard one :)

Comment: You could do this with javascript, but you're going to code a whole infrastructure for this. You need to implement some kind of script with some basic styling and attributes which will load content from your site with a shortcode/embed code. This is something only an experienced javascript developer is able to do. My speciality is WordPress and PHP, so I'm unable to help you with this.

Comment: Thanks I might have found something, so I will test it tonight before I confirm it. Basically it is creating a .js file as a container with document.write("<iframe src='http://somedomain/.../some-widget'></iframe>"); and create blank pages with just the shortcodes or whatever content needed to be displayed. Although I need this for a membership site, I believe it is possible to do. I am going to test it tonight and see what I can come up with.